# iOS 9 Stanford Course in Swift - Lecture 1

Tags: ios, swift, cs193p

I'm currently trying to complete the Swift Course on iTunes U and we are building a calculator. I'm having trouble understanding part of the code.

I added the code below that I thought was relevant from the file.

Here is what confuses me: why does operation(operand) compute the value for the UnaryOperation (i.e. the square root)? I see that when the CalculatorBrain class is called the dictionary is initialized, but when I print the dictionary out I just get something that looks like this: [✕: ✕, -: -, +: +, ⌹: ⌹, √: √]. So where/when does the program compute the square root when I click on the square root button?

```
Class CalculatorBrain
    {
    private enum Op: Printable
    {
    case Operand(Double)
    case UnaryOperation(String, Double -> Double)
    case BinaryOperation(String, (Double, Double) -> Double)

    var description: String {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .Operand(let operand):
                return "\(operand)"
            case .UnaryOperation(let symbol, _):
                return symbol
            case .BinaryOperation(let symbol, _):
                return symbol
            }
        }
    }
}

private var opStack = [Op]()

private var knownOps = [String: Op]()

init() {
    func learnOp(op: Op) {
        knownOps[op.description] = op

    }
    learnOp(Op.BinaryOperation("✕", *))
    learnOp(Op.BinaryOperation("⌹") { $1 / $0 })
    learnOp(Op.BinaryOperation("+", +))
    learnOp(Op.BinaryOperation("-") { $0 - $1 })
    learnOp(Op.UnaryOperation ("√", sqrt))

}

private func evaluate(ops: [Op]) -> (result: Double?, remainingOps: [Op])
{
    if !ops.isEmpty {
        var remainingOps = ops
        let op = remainingOps.removeLast()
        switch op {
        case .Operand(let operand):
        return (operand, remainingOps)
        case .UnaryOperation(_, let operation):
            let operandEvaluation = evaluate(remainingOps)
            if let operand = operandEvaluation.result {
                **return (operation(operand), operandEvaluation.remainingOps)**
            }
        // case.BinaryOperation(.....)
        }
    }
    return (nil, ops)
}

 func evaluate() -> Double? {
    let (result, remainder) = evaluate(opStack)
    return result
}

func pushOperand(operand: Double) -> Double? {
    opStack.append(Op.Operand(operand))
    return evaluate()
}

func performOperation(symbol: String) -> Double? {
    if let operation = knownOps[symbol] {
        opStack.append(operation)
    }
   return evaluate()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Op` enum implements the `Printable` protocol, which means it has a `description: String` property.  When you print the `Dictionary`, you are sending `[String : Op]` to the `println` function which then tries to print the `Op` using its `description`.

The reason the description of the operators is the same as its key in the `Dictionary` is because the `learnOp(op: Op)` function sets the key to be `op.description` (`knownOps[op.description] = op`)

To see the effects of this, you could add a new operator `learnOp(Op.UnaryOperation ("@", sqrt))` which will be printed as `@:@` inside of the `knownOps` Dictionary. (And if you add a new button for the `@` operator, it will also perform the square root operation)

---

Since the calculator is stack based, the operands get pushed on, then the operations.  When `evaluate()` gets called, it calls `evaluate(opStack)` passing the entire stack through.

`evaluate(ops: [Op])` then takes the to item off of the stack and evaluates the function *after* having calculated the operands.

As an example, lets say you want to calucalte sqrt(4 + 5).

You would push the items onto the stack, and it would look like: `[ 4, 5, +, sqrt ]`

Then `evaluate(ops: [Op])` sees the `sqrt` and evaluates the operand with a recursive call.  That call then evaluates `+` with two more recursive calls which return `5` and `4`.

The tree of calls would look like this:

```
ops: [4, 5, +, sqrt]    // Returns sqrt(9) = 3
          |
   ops: [4, 5, +]       // Returns 4 + 5 = 9
      ____|_____
     |          |
ops: [4, 5]  ops: [4]
return 5     return 4
```

I strongly recommend you put a breakpoint on the `evaluate() -> Double?` function and step through the program to see where it goes with different operands and operations.

Comment: Okay great--that cleared up why the dictionary was being printed that way. Thank you!! But when does the square root function get called? I'm still not seeing the connection between return (operation(operand), operandEvaluation.remainingOps)

Comment: @Sami I added some more information about how the program actually executes.

Answer (score 0):

```
learnOp(Op.UnaryOperation ("√", sqrt))
```

sqrt is a built in function, so you're teaching the calculator that "√" means it should perform the sqrt operation.

Comment: Okay, so I teach the calculator to perform the square root operation--but when does the square root operation get called? I'm having trouble seeing  the connection of: return (operation(operand), operandEvaluation.remainingOps) and  learnOp(Op.UnaryOperation ("√", sqrt))